# I am using click event to trigger a new page to generate the drill down data from highcharts however the entire chart is being generated

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to build a drill down table from the charts of the particular category being clicked,
I am using click event to trigger a new page to generate the drill down tabular data from high charts however the entire chart data is being generated.
How do get the data of the particular element being clicked from the chart?
I am able to extract the category of the point being clicked but not the series data. I comes up as undefined.

alert(this.options.name) is giving undefined.

Check the jsfiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/VM001/90jpvdw3/2/

```
 point:{
     events:{
         click: function () {
             location.href ="clickTable";
             alert('Category:'+this.category+',values:'+this.y)
             alert(this.options.name)
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Why don't you add that snippet to your question if it's relevant?

Comment: use this.series.xData will give you all x-axis data and this.series.yData will give you y-axis data is that sufficient  or use console.log(this) to get the JSON  Highchart Object and traverse thought the console you can get any data present on the chart;

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.
However, alert(this) is not giving the json object.

If the user clicks on the first bar, i want to sent Q1 and 2019 to my code so that i can generate a tabular data for user from there.

Comment: Just like in the answer - you can get access to the series options through the `this.series` object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 point:{
     events:{
         click: function () {
             location.href ="clickTable";
             alert('Category:'+this.category+',values:'+this.y)
             alert(this.series.name)
         }
     }
 }
```